# How to convert != to ≠ and -> to → in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

In some video tutorials, I saw that `Android Studio` automatically converts `!=` and `->` to equivalent unicode characters. How can I config my `Android Studio` for doing this?

Comment: google for "intellij font ligature"

Comment: https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is just the font not Android Studio actually you can use it in any text editor/IDE and get the same result you can find link to [Fira code](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode) font.

#### Instructions for Android Studio:

**Version 2016.2 and later**

Proper support for ligatures was added in 2016.2 (incl. font compatibility & better performance).
- Enable in `Settings` → `Editor` → `Colors & Fonts` → `Font` → `Enable Font Ligatures`
- Select `Fira Code` as "Primary font" under `Settings` → `Editor` → `Colors & Fonts` → `Font` → `Editor Font`

NOTE that since 2016.3 IntelliJ products come with Fira Code bundled with the editor itself. If you want latest version of Fira Code, install it separately & restart your editor.